# Trying to access mongo database hosted on server A from server B but i keep getting ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: mongodb, security, ssh, server, timeout

I am trying to access a mongo database hosted on ssh server A from server B. Server B doesn't have mongo installed on it so I am using a python code to install it but i keep getting this error:

```
Collection content:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pritika/mongotest.py", line 20, in <module>
    for document in collection.find():
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1264, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1155, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1823, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 573, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 589, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/root/pritika/ner/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 259, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: **.***.**.96:27017: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65d83cef7c09f97c4c3dcd05, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('**.***.**.96', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('**.***.**.96:27017: timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>
```

I am using this code:

```
import pymongo
import urllib.parse
usernamee = "username"
passwords = "password"

username = urllib.parse.quote_plus(usernamee)
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(passwords)
host = "**.***.**.96" 
port = 27017
database_name = "dbName"
collection_name = "dbCollection"

uri = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database_name}"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

db = client[database_name]
collection = db[collection_name]

print("Collection content:")
for document in collection.find():
    print(document)
```

The database is intact and the server A is running fine. I tried searching but i am not able to resolve it. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the setting for [net.bindIp](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.bindIp)?

Comment: I am not sure about that. Can you tell me how do i check it?

Comment: Check the MongoDB configuration file. Or more generic, run command `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: this is the info i could find that you are possibly asking "net" : {
                        "bindIp" : "127.0.0.1",
                        "port" : 27017
                },

Comment: `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` means, the MongoDB listens only to the localhost, i.e. you can connect only from local machine. Try `bindIpAll: true` to permit connections from remote machine.

Comment: i am login as root so how do i change it to `bindIpAll: true` Can you share me the steps to do so

Comment: It is the configuration file of your MongoDB. How do you start it?

Comment: I just type Mongo in the terminal and it launches. Also, I couldn't find any separate MongoDB config file stored on my server

Comment: `--bind_ip localhost` is the default. Try `--bind_ip_all`

Comment: Note that binding Mongo on all IPs make it accessible from anywhere on the Internet. Make sure that it requires a valid user account to login and that all user accounts have a string password.